# How to put output to a different text file in flex

Tags: linux

I have written a simple program to check the words of a text file is verb or not using flex. But I want to put (print) the output to a different text file.
Is it possible? How will I do that?

My sample code is:

```
%%

[\t]+

is   |

am   |

are  |

was  |

were {printf("%s: is a verb",yytext);}

[a-zA-Z]+ {printf("%s: is a verb",yytext);}

. |\n

%%

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){    
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");    
    yylex();         
    fclose(yyin);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know not enough about `lex`/`flex` to be sure, but, given the code I see in the question, I'd try to add this code to `main()`:

```
FILE * myfd = fopen(argv[2], "w");
```

and use `fprintf()` instead of `printf()`, as in:

```
{ fprintf(myfd, "%s: is a verb", yytext); }
```

I used `argv[2]` as source of the file name, which means you have to provide it as second argument in the program call, but you can also hard-code a string with a file name.

Comment: can you please define the format of calling a.out file in linux for the above procedure? @Janis

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. Just guessing; if you compile the code from your `lex`/`yacc` or `flex`/`bison` definitions without explicitly specifying a filename you'll get a file called `a.out`. You probably have invoked the command before the change like this: `a.out textfile`, where `textfile` is your input file that gets parsed. With another new parameter for specifying the output file your call would be something like: `a.out textfile outputfile`, where `outputfile` would be written by your parser program.

Comment: to run the a.out file I have used ./a.out<inputfile  where inputfile is the input file. now with another parameter, will the syntax be like this: ./a.out<inputfile<outputfile
or anything else? @Janis

Comment: The `<` is a redirection of the standard input channel. With a program that accesses files through `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` that makes no sense. If a program accesses files through names provided as parameters that would be as I'be shown in my previous comment, or, with your files names, that would be `./a.out inputfile outputfile`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just let your script print the results to *stdout* (normal terminal output) and then redirect it to a file with the **`>`**-operator:

Assuming your script is the file `/home/USERNAME/bin/isVerb` and you want to check the word "procrastinate", you would run it like this:

```
/home/USERNAME/bin/isVerb procrastinate > /home/USERNMAE/Documents/isVerb-procrastinate.txt
```

The command will create the file `/home/USERNMAE/Documents/isVerb-procrastinate.txt` or replace it if it already exists and save the output into it.
If you prefer the command to append the output to a file (if it already exists, otherwise create it), you use **`>>`** instead of `>`.